# scopre of variable defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

So I have following base script for common functions that are to be used throughout project. Let's call this **base.js** with following code.

**base.js**

```
(function(document, window, undefined, $){

    if (typeof $ === undefined) {
        throw new Error("Site requires jQuery");
    }

    $.SPA = {};

    $.SPA.showAlert = function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    };

})(document, window, undefined, jQuery);
```

And I can have different scripts that are to be loaded in specific pages.

Now suppose I have page say, *dashboard*, it loads **dashboard.js** with following code -

**dashboard.js**

```
$(function() {
    $.SPA.showAlert("Bazzinga");
});
```

So I have access to `$.SPA` with no problem. But my question is, is this correct or may cause issues with `$.SPA` scope or any chance of overriding it from other scripts ?

Comment: any script could override it.. but this all that we can do... another solution is to use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and make it a non writable value - in modern browsers only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my question is, is this correct or may cause issues with $.SPA
>   scope or any chance of overriding it from other scripts ?

`$.SPA` is in global scope because `$` has global scope.

And yes, other scripts can override it since they also has access to this variable which is true for most objects in JavaScript as it is designed to be extensible.

You can make an object immutable by using [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```
Object.freeze($.SPA);
```

Add this line by the end of your IIFE as

```
(function(document, window, undefined, $){

    if (typeof $ === undefined) {
        throw new Error("Site requires jQuery");
    }

    $.SPA = {};

    $.SPA.showAlert = function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    };

    Object.freeze($.SPA);

})(document, window, undefined, jQuery);
```

**Edit :**

As per the comment from @ArunPJohny, you need to use define property as well since freeze alone is not enough.

```
(function(document, window, undefined, $){

    if (typeof $ === undefined) {
        throw new Error("Site requires jQuery");
    }

    $.SPA = {};

    $.SPA.showAlert = function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    };
    Object.defineProperty($, 'SPA', {
     enumerable: true,
     configurable: false,
     writable: false,
     value: {}
   });    

    Object.freeze($.SPA);

})(document, window, undefined, jQuery);
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny as per doc I have pointed to it will prevent, just that it won't throw an error. For throwing an error, strict mode has to be enabled.

Comment: The document is correct, it just freezes the object assigned to `SPA` property, we still the `SPA` property of `$` is writable... so just using `freeze` will not solve the issue.... you need to define the property such that it is not writable

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks, made the changes to address shallow freeze